# Variable for a "for loop"

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

I've got two variables and I'm trying to run a for loop from one of them:

```
a=5  
z="i=0;i<=$a;i++"
x="i=$a;i>=1;i--"
read -p "choose loop:" loop
  case "$loop" in
    plus ) l="$z" ;;
    minus ) l="$x" ;;
  esac

for (($l)) do
#also tried (('$l')) & (("$l"))
  ...
done
```

When I'm doing this I've got:

```
syntax error: arithmetic expression requiered
syntax error:'(($l))'
```

So I tried:

```
a=5
x="\(\(i=1;i<=$a;i++\)\)"
#also tried "((...))"

for $x do
  ...
done
#also tried "$x" & '$x'
```

But when I'm doing this i've got:

`bash: '"$l"': not a valid identifier`.

But I want only one "loop construction" I don't want to copy my code twice.
So what should i do for run my loop and don't have to write my code twice inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the list in a variable using `seq`:

```
loop_max=5
read -p "choose loop:" loop
case "$loop" in
  plus) myseq=$(seq 0 "$loop_max");;
  minus) myseq=$(seq "$loop_max" -1 0);;
esac

for i in $myseq; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

**Edit:**

You can also set the `seq` arguments in the `case` statement and call `seq` in you `for` loop:

```
loop_max=5
read -p "choose loop:" loop
case "$loop" in
  plus) start="0";;
  minus) end="-1 0";;
esac

for i in $(seq $start "$loop_max" $end); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: This is very elegant!

Comment: Thanks @codeforester. I was thinking of using just one `seq` command but I found it would have been less readable.

Comment: @SLePort Just for knowledge you can post how you do with only `seq` command ?

Comment: @SLePort , first one is good for understand but second one is shortest and even more what i was really excepting for . Thanks you .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `for` syntax allows what you are trying to do.  Instead, do this to keep it more readable:

```
loop_max=5
read -p "choose loop:" loop
case "$loop" in
   plus) loop_type="ascending"
    ;;
  minus) loop_type="descending"
    ;;
esac

[[ $loop_type == "ascending" ]] && for ((i = 0; i <= $loop_max; i++)); do
  : your code goes here
done

[[ $loop_type == "descending" ]] && for ((i = $loop_max; i > 0; i--)); do
  : your code goes here
done
```

---

The `case` statement is not adding much value.  So, you could rewrite the whole thing this way:

```
loop_max=5
read -p "choose loop:" loop_type
if [[ $loop_type == "plus" ]]; then
  for ((i = 0; i <= $loop_max; i++)); do
    : your code goes here
  done
elif [[ $loop_type == "minus" ]]; then
  for ((i = $loop_max; i > 0; i--)); do
    : your code goes here
  done
else
  printf "Invalid choice.\n"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your for loop to look like this:

```
for j in $l 
do
    echo $j; # whatever you need to do here 
done
```

Hope this will solve your purpose.

Comment: Did you test it?  It won't iterate the way OP wants it - it will run the loop only once with `j` set to the value of `$l`.

Comment: @codeforester, I see that you have posted the correct answer. I tried to address his issues with "not a valid identifier" error that he was facing. As is evident from your answer, there are multiple issues with his script.